# handle a data.frame with "date" column that includes NULL values

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to compare two 'date string' columns like:

`df$inpatient.death = (df$date.of.death==df$date.of.discharge)`

BUT: the occurrence of `NULL` values seems to prevent me from formatting `as.Date`, and the different format from using as.character(..)==as.character(..).
What's the best way of creating

```
                                                    THIS IS THE AIM:
  id           date.of.death date.of.discharge    [ inpatient.death ]
1  1 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000        2012-01-01    [            TRUE ]
2  2                    NULL        2012-01-01    [           FALSE ]
3  3 2012-01-02 00:00:00.000        2012-01-01    [           FALSE ]

df <- data.frame(id=1:3, date.of.death=c("2012-01-01 00:00:00.000", "NULL", "2012-01-02 00:00:00.000"), date.of.discharge=c("2012-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-01-01"))
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Where do the `NULL` values come from? In R `NA` is used for missing values and your data.frame should not contain any `NULL` values. That means you do something unusual to create that data.frame and should try to correct that. Another possibility would be to use `df$date.of.death[is.null(df$date.of.death)] <- NA`.

Comment: Note that your example df just contains a character `"NULL"` which is not a `NULL` value. If you have that, you should probably use the `na.strings` argument of `read.table` or whichever function you use to read your file.

Comment: @Roland : "NULL" came from a csv import, but I have since managed to convert to as.Date using as.Date(df$date.of.death,"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000")

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:3, date.of.death=c("2012-01-01 00:00:00.000", "NULL", "2012-01-02 00:00:00.000"),
                 date.of.discharge=c("2012-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-01-01"))

df$inpatient.death <- as.Date(df$date.of.death)==as.Date(df$date.of.discharge) # date.of.death is already in the standard format no need to specify
df$inpatient.death[is.na(df$inpatient.death)] <- F

> df
  id           date.of.death date.of.discharge inpatient.death
1  1 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000        2012-01-01            TRUE
2  2                    NULL        2012-01-01           FALSE
3  3 2012-01-02 00:00:00.000        2012-01-01           FALSE

# you can also definy an helper function for this task

`==2` <- function(x,y){
  res <- x==y
  res[is.na(res)] <- F
  res
}

df$inpatient.death <- `==2`(as.Date(df$date.of.death),as.Date(df$date.of.discharge))

> df
  id           date.of.death date.of.discharge inpatient.death
1  1 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000        2012-01-01            TRUE
2  2                    NULL        2012-01-01           FALSE
3  3 2012-01-02 00:00:00.000        2012-01-01           FALSE
```